# Does asp.net identity 2.0 hash passwords differently than 1.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I just updated my app from asp.net identity 1.0 to 2.0 to take advantage of the email confirmation, two-factor auth, etc...

However, user's cannot log in now. It seems `await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);` doesn't find existing users who signed up on identity 1.0... but user's who signed up during identity 2.0 work fine.

Comment: Hashing should be the same, Both identity 1 and 2 use System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes to hash the password, which is a hash+salt method following strict OWASP guidelines.

Comment: Not only that, but the storage of hashes are such that even if new hash algorithms are added or changed, then the old algorithms should still be able to be used to match the passwords.  So obviously there must be another problem here.  Perhaps you should just have users reset their passwords.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking deeper into the issue. I think it may have something to do with the way the new RavenDB Identity provider stores the `ApplicationUser`. Still good to know asp.net identity hashes the same across versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashing is exactly the same.
Identity 2.0 `UserManager.FindAsync(UserName, Password)` can return null for users registered with Identity 1.0.
There are some new fields in the `AspNetUsers` table which are manadatory - NOT NULL.
Most possible reason is the `AccessFailedCount` field. If it is null, you don't see any exceptions, only null user.