# Create asp.net Identity User in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-identity

This question is a revised version of the previous one (I deleted that one)

I have a site running `(C#) MVC 5` and `ASP.Net Identity 2.0`. From within the site all user management functions works fine, create, update, delete.

We have a SQL job that created all the accounts in bulk on the previous version of the site, I now need to update this to create the new accounts in `Identity 2.0`. I can't find any information on how to do this in any of the available forums.

Any information would be appreciated.

I've done some work on it an the last issue I have is figuring out how `Identity 2.0` encodes the password. I can't seem to find out what algorithm is used.

This is how Identity 1 encoded the password:

```
SET @encoded_hashed_password = dbo.fbase64_encode(HASHBYTES('SHA1', Cast(@salt as varbinary(MAX)) + CAST(@ClearTextPassword AS varbinary(MAX))))
```

I'm looking for the Identity 2.0 equivalent.

Comment: It's exactly the same according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026912/does-asp-net-identity-2-0-hash-passwords-differently-than-1-0

Comment: I've looked at that post, it's not that same. Identity 2.0 uses pbkdf2, 1.0 does not.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the same algorithm you will find in [System.Web.Helpers.Crypto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto(v=vs.111).aspx) to hash and verify the passwords.  To hash the password the method [HashPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.hashpassword(v=vs.111).aspx) can be used. The password hash is generated with the RFC 2898 algorithm using a 128-bit salt, a 256-bit subkey, and 1000 iterations. The format of the generated hash bytestream is {0x00, salt, subkey}, which is base-64 encoded before it is returned.

It is not clear to me from the question whether the previous site used SimpleMembership.  If it was here is an [article that provides detailed steps to migrate to ASP.NET Identity](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2014/02/migrating-existing-website-from.html) and how you can just use the same hash for your passwords.

Comment: Thanks kevin, the problem is not migrating, the problem is creating the new accounts (brand new users, not existing ones from the previous site) in a SQL job. Each job will have to create a few hundred accounts, so I need to find a script that can hash the password successfully.

Comment: T-SQL does not have anything built in to perform this type of hash. But you can call .Net methods from it.  You can use the method I mentioned above (Crypto.HashPassword).  Here is an example on how to call a simple common language runtime (CLR) integration-based stored procedure. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878250.aspx

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I figured that the CLR route is the best solution to the problem.